# Possible to create an implicit style that is used, by default, as the base for other styles?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, controltemplate

I'm trying to figure out a way to create an implicit style for a custom control, that will be inherited by other styles applied to the control.

For example, let's say I have a control `FancyButton`.  Then I can define an implicit style by putting this in my app resources:

```
<Style TargetType="my:FancyButton">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="my:FancyButton">
                <TextBlock Text="hello world" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Then users of the control will see "hello world" in green just by writing:

```
<my:FancyButton Foreground="Green" />
```

The problem is, if someone wants to define a green-colored style like this ...

```
<Style TargetType="my:FancyButton" x:Key="GreenButton">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
</Style>

<my:FancyButton Style="{StaticResource GreenButton}" />
```

... then they will have lost the implicit style's control template, and will not see the "hello world".

Of course, you can define a base style, which the implicit style inherits ...

```
<Style TargetType="my:FancyButton" x:Key="FancyButtonDefaultStyle">
    <!-- ... -->
</Style>

<Style TargetType="my:FancyButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource FancyButtonDefaultStyle}">
</Style>
```

... and that way users of the control can inherit the default style:

```
<Style TargetType="my:FancyButton" x:Key="GreenButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource FancyButtonDefaultStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
</Style>
```

But it seems awkward to force users of the control to remember to inherit a default style based on a key.  Isn't there some way to make a custom control's styles inherit the implicit style, in the same way that the framework controls do?

Ie, I want my FancyButton to behave in the same way a `Button` does, where I can define a style that doesn't wipe out the other default style properties (esp. ControlTemplate):

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="GreenButton">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
</Style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the implicit style definition

```
<Style TargetType="my:FancyButton">
    <!-- etc -->
</Style>
```

in the special "Themes/Generic.xaml" resource dictionary (in the same assembly as where the control class is defined). This makes all styles inherit from the implicit style, as you wanted.

Sorry for quoting. :)

Hope this helps.

Here's my code:
MainPage.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication4.MainPage"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SilverlightApplication4"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="300"
             d:DesignWidth="400">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>                

            <Style TargetType="local:TemplatedControl1"
                   x:Key="myCustomTemplate">

                <Setter Property="Foreground"
                        Value="Purple" />
            </Style>

        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"
          Background="Yellow"
          Width="500"
          Height="500">

        <local:TemplatedControl1 Style="{StaticResource myCustomTemplate}" />             

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Now in TemplatedControl.cs don't forget to put this:

```
this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(TemplatedControl1);
```

And finally put your implicit style definition in Themes\Generic.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SilverlightApplication4">

    <Style TargetType="local:TemplatedControl1">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:TemplatedControl1">
                    <TextBlock Text="hello world"
                               Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

With this method, the result should be purple text in a terrible yellow background. :)

Comment: Thanks for catching the typo.  The code "works", but the question I'm asking is: is it possible to set it up so that users of the control can just write `<Style TargetType="my:FancyButton" x:Key="GreenButton">` (ie, without having to use `BasedOn`).

Comment: Let me add another answer to include some code as well.

Comment: Have you actually tested this?  I tried your example, but for `<local:TemplatedControl1 Style="{StaticResource myCustomTemplate}" />`, I see nothing.  For `<local:TemplatedControl1 Foreground="Blue" />` I see "hello world" in blue text.

Comment: Of course I tried it. This is very strange. What SL version are you using? I'm using 5.1.30214.0 with IE8. I'll give it a try with IE11 tomorrow.

Comment: Same here, version 5.1.30214.0.  I don't see the browser version could make any difference ...?

Comment: Can you verify that you put the implicit style definition in Themes\generic.xaml? If this is not the case, can you pls give that a try?

Comment: I had not done that, no ... but after updating, that did not make a difference either.

Comment: Nevermind, got it working!  I had my control sitting in a library class, which for some reason prevented the default theme from getting applied.  Thanks so much.

Comment: One request before I accept your answer: would you mind editing (or giving me permission to do so), to remove the part about the typo, and add a short note at the top emphasizing the key point that the implicit style must go in "Themes/Generic.xaml"?  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Tanis83 for pointing out the (very simple) answer.  I just needed to put the implicit style ...

```
<Style TargetType="my:FancyButton">
    <!-- etc -->
</Style>
```

in the special "Themes/Generic.xaml" resource dictionary (in the same assembly as where the control class is defined).  This makes all styles inherit from the implicit style, as I wanted.

Comment: Either that or just throw it at the bottom of a resource dict with your BasedOn there for global inheritance `<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource FancyButtonDefaultStyle}" TargetType="my:FancyButton"/>` and of course I miss a rare opportunity where I could have actually answered one of yours for a change instead of vice versa...